# Is it possible to have an application written on Python, but with embedded C++ into it?

Tags: python, c++, kivy, embedding

I would like to know if i can have a mobile application written on Python(for example, for interface), but with embedded C++ for some tasks or functions of the app? For example, an application written with Kivy Framework for its interface, and with C++ for some AI features. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to write the necessary library in C++ and then use it in Python. Though this is going to require some tricks that you can find online as you make your library. One example of this (since you want to use AI) is TensorFlow; it is used in Python while its core is written in C++